# nodejs copying SHA-1 encrypted plain/text file by its file contents (without decrypting)

Tags: node.js, encryption, hash, clone

i'm trying to clone a SHA-1 encrypted plain/text file via its file contents without decrypting it in my script

i use fs.readFileSync(path, 'base64') and I copy the data returned into a new file but when I come to decrypt that new file it says corrupted

why is this method different to copy/pasting the file using my OS GUI (which has no errors)? am i missing some
metadata or something?

**edit**

fs.createstream piped into write stream works but its not kinda what i want to do. basically i want the file data to be placed into an object so i can save it to a variable and write to files dynamically.

**edit2**

my code:

```
console.log(fs.readFileSync(<pathtofile>), 'base64');
```

i then copy the output, paste it into a new file and try to decrypt that file but it says corrupted

Comment: Can you include more of your code?

Comment: I would guess you are writing the `base64` encoding of the file back out

Comment: yes what should i be doing instead?

Comment: What do you actually mean by _SHA-1 encrypted_? SHA1 is a hashing algorithm that creates a 20 bytes hash. A decryption is _principally_ not possible. And, is the file really Base64 encoded? What happens if you omit the encoding (`'base64'`), i.e. if you read the data into a buffer and process it from there, e.g. write to another file? It would be easier if you post your code.